# How can I link directly to an answer?

Tags: support, answers

Sometimes it is useful, when commenting on a question or answer, to link to an answer that was given to anther question. On other sites, I do this by using the "share" link under the desired link target to get a URL that goes specifically to that answer. But that "share" link doesn't seem to exist here at present, presumably because we're in private beta.

How else can I link to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hack. I hope there is a better way.

Go to the answer post. You will see the small `edit` link at the bottom.

> [image]

Hover or click on it. You will see/go-to a url of the form:

```
http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/358/edit
```

The number in the URL is the post ID. Now, add it to the answer short link.

```
http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/358
```

And, there you have it!

Comment: Thanks - sounds like this may be the only way for a few weeks.

Answer (score 5):

Once we graduate into public beta, you'll see a 'share' button near each question and answer:

[image]

However, for *right now*, AsheeshR's answer is the easiest way to do it.